# JQuery carusel

Tags: jquery

Люди добрые.
Сами мы не местные и вообще. :) Где найти примеры карусели на JQuery, чтобы блоки друг под друга заходили, т.е. вращались по центральной оси? Весь инет уже облазил - не могу даже названия для этой карусели для поискового запроса придумать. :)
Пример на картинке http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/jquery-carousel-evolution.jpg

Заранее большое спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень похоже на ImageFlow: http://finnrudolph.de/produkte/imageflow

**Обновление**

Если посмотреть в исходники, то там есть жёсткая завязка:

```
if (node && node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == 'IMG')
```

то есть только картинки.

Comment: Да-да-да. Спасибо большое. Оно и есть. Правда, пока не ясно - оно для блоков работает или только для img... У меня с JS давняя нелюбовь, поэтому пользуюсь готовыми скриптами, чуть-чуть переделывая. А тут заказчику нужно вот, хоть вешайся, такая штука. Буду ковырять в Инете ImageFlow.

Comment: Обновил ответ